# Pyautogui Locate on Screen taking too much time on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, time, windows-10, pyautogui

I have written below `Pyautogui` code in Windows 10.

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time
time.sleep(3)
while True:
    if pg.locateOnScreen('Music.png',grayscale=True):
        pg.click(pg.locateCenterOnScreen('Music.png',grayscale=True))
        break
```

I am trying to locate the image on the page in Windows 10, its taking 27 seconds to read the image

As compared to when i was using *Windows 7* it was very fast, in Windows 7 it reads the images very quickly

I tried defining specific region to shorten the search but sometime those images varies from one position to another position.

What setting should i do so that in Windows 10 it start reading the images quickly or what code i write to make the image/locate on screen function faster.

Comment: Have you figured it out whether the whole program is slow or just the image locating function?

Comment: Just the image locating function is slow, rest taking screenshot and other functions are working fine. Earlier it was fine in windows 7 but when i upgraded to windows 10 location on screen function is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is always inside a region you can add region to your code that it runs faster. I had the same problem and my code went from 9 seconds to under 1 second.
for example:

```
import time
time.sleep(3)
while True:
    if pg.locateOnScreen('Music.png',region=(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000)grayscale=True): #by the region it is called #top, left, width, height
        pg.click(pg.locateCenterOnScreen('Music.png',grayscale=True))
        break
```

If you specify that region maybe it will work. :)
And maybe check the docs again.
https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html